# Wie sagt man »to stand someone up«?

Tags: grammar, translation, english-to-german

> Sie ließ mich gestern im Café sitzen.
>
> She stood me up yesterday at the café.

Ich weiß nicht, ob `sitzen lassen` hier richtig ist.

Was ist die Alternativ dazu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"jemanden sitzen lassen" geht, oder "jemanden versetzen".

Comment: Wobei "jemanden sitzen lassen" auch das einseitige Beenden einer Beziehung bedeutet oder das vorzeitige Verlassen  des Treffens im Café. "Versetzen" ist eindeutig das Nichterscheinen zu einem vereinbarten Treffen.

Comment: @Stephie richtig... die Bedeutung ergibt sich dann aus dem Kontext.

Comment: Wollte nur vermeiden, dass Leser den Umkehrschluss ziehen - sitzen lassen gleich stand so. up.